# Problems with selected indices in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, arraylist

I have an arraylist which contain objects of my own class. I want to fetch the object from the array list which has the index = selectedindex of listview.

I tried this :

```
TrackInformation t=(TrackInformation) SongList[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]];
```

`TrackInformation` is my class and `SongList` is an ArrayList of type `TrackInformation`.

listview1 does not allow multiple indices selection so I want the first element of the `SelectedIndices` collection.

I am getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and it says value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: Are you sure is any item selected on your UI? Exception says itself that no item is selected on UI. In that case only index can be out of range.

Comment: the code is written in `listview1_SelectedIndexChanged`, so yes, an item is definitely selected.

Comment: When you de-select the item from UI in that case also selection changed event got raised. Try using the `Ctrl+Mouse Click` on the selected item in that case also event will be raised. So before calling your code you need to check `if(listView1.SelectedIndices.Count>0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView.SelectedIndexChanged event has a quirk that bombs your code.  When you start your program, no item is selected.  Click an item and SelectedIndexChanged fires, no problem.  Now click another item and the event fires *twice*.  First to let you know, unhelpfully, that the first item is *unselected*.  Then again to tell you that the new item is selected.  That first event is going to make you index an empty array, kaboom.  RV1987's snippet prevents this.

Answer (score 3):

Put this line before your code -

```
if(listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
{
   TrackInformation t=(TrackInformation) SongList[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]];
}
```

Comment: You need to make it clear to continue the logic inside the `if`, as  `t` won't exits outside the scope of the `if`

Answer (score 1):

The error is because listView1.SelectedIndices is empty, do you have a row selected?

you probable want to wrap in a test

```
ListView.SelectedIndexCollection selected=listView1.SelectedIndicies;

if (selected.Count==0) {
 // code for no items selected
} else {
  TrackInformation t=(TrackInformation) SongList[selected[0]]; 
  // rest of code to deal with t
}
```