# Getting the index of a selected item in my ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have the following code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Index.Text = listView1.SelectedIndices[0].ToString();
}
```

Where `Index` is a `Label` control element. Selecting the first item on the list gives me a text `0`, which is correct. Selecting the second item on the list returns me:

```
Exception Unhandled: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument = Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

Why did the above happen? I've also tried `listView1.SelectedIndex`. However, it seems like said method is not accessible from my version of C#.

Comment: is it a winform application?

Comment: @MihirDave yes it is.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922872/problems-with-selected-indices-in-listview

Comment: @MihirDave I see, that's so silly. But I guess logically, that's how it should go (unselecting then selecting again).